# How to login to windows 8 kindle app

Tags: kindle, amazon, windows

I have an account on amazon.ca and I can login properly and it works to buy and read books from the kindle store. But when I go onto the kindle app for windows 8.1, it says that there is no account with my email and password. I am guessing this is just because the kindle app is trying to access the US server/database, but my account is for the canadian kindle/amazon server. If this is the case, is there any way of changing the server it accesses or linking two accounts accross amazon.com and amazon.ca. If not has anyone had the same problem, and how did you fix it?

Comment: This `might` help, but I'm not sure to be honest http://www.amazon.ca/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201159440 Your best bet is to contact customer service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that they have two kindle apps for windows. One that you download from their website and one from the windows store. the one on the windows store is the one I had problems with, the one I downloaded on the website works perfectly fine. This is more of a work around than a solution, but it works.